# How to incorporate weights into a likelihood function?

Tags: r, regression, mle

I want to incorporate weights into the likelihood to do what the `svyglm` does with weights.

According to [Jeremy Miles](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/57107) and [elsewhere](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf), `svyglm` function uses weights to "weight the importance of each case to make them representative (to each other, ...)".

Here is my data:

```
(dat <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 1, 0, 0), B = c(1, 0, 1, 0),
  Pass = c(278, 100, 153, 79), Fail = c(743, 581, 1232, 1731), Weights= c(3, 1, 12, 3)
))
```

Here is my `likelihood` function:

```
ll <- function (b0, b1, b2, b3) {
  odds <- exp(b0) * (1 + b1 * dat$A + b2 * dat$B + b3 * dat$A * dat$B)
  -sum(dbinom(
    x = dat$Pass, size = rowSums(dat[, 3:4]),
    prob = odds / (1 + odds), log = TRUE))
}
```

Comment: I can't really see what's the relation between survey weights and, I guess, simply weighted maximum likelihood. Doing `-sum(dat$Weights * dbinom(...` would give more importance to the cases with higher weights. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: I think your solution works. It seems it is what I am looking for. Just let me ask this: Is the likelihood contribution of each observation that is being weighted in your solution?

Comment: Yes, we may interpret it like that. Doubling the log likelihood/contribution of x_i = including x_i twice.

Comment: Thank you very much for that @Julius Vainora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is said in your referred answers, different weights are used differently in different contexts. In your current example I don't really see any populations, while the goal is pretty clear: for each observation to have a specified "importance". Then the weighted maximum likelihood would simply use

```
ll <- function (b0, b1, b2, b3) {
  odds <- exp(b0) * (1 + b1 * dat$A + b2 * dat$B + b3 * dat$A * dat$B)
  -sum(dat$Weights * dbinom(
    x = dat$Pass, size = rowSums(dat[, 3:4]),
    prob = odds / (1 + odds), log = TRUE))
}
```

That can indeed be interpreted as including the i-th observation to the sample w<sub>i</sub> times (this interpretation, of course, is exactly true only for integer weights, while the method works with any weights):

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much  @Julius Vainora. That is exactly what I was looking for.